# Elasticsearch with Rails - mapping `_all` field in 2.2 version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I got a multi model search and my configuration looks like:

```
settings analysis: {
  ...
} do
  mappings do
    indexes "_all",
      type: "string",
      analyzer: "ngram_analyzer",
      search_analyzer: "whitespace_analyzer"
  end
end
```

It all worked great on Elasticsearch 2.1 but breaks on 2.2 with:

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400]
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [insurer]: Field [_all] is defined twice in [insurer]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [insurer]: Field [_all] is defined twice in [insurer]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "Field [_all] is defined twice in [insurer]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

How can fix it to index `all` fields in 2.2?

Comment: Does this happen on a fresh 2.2 node? Can you try once clearing the indices if there are any conflicting ones for `insurer` type?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it turned out I need to change mappings to:

```
settings analysis: {
  ...
} do
  mappings _all: {
    type: "string", analyzer: "ngram_analyzer", search_analyzer: "whitespace_analyzer"
  }
end
```

It works well now.